# Prove equality of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V,W$ be $K$-vector spaces and $S$ a $K$-basis of $V$. Suppose that $V$ is ﬁnite dimensional.

1. Let $\varphi_1,\varphi_2: V → W$ be $K$-linear maps. Suppose $\varphi_1(s) = \varphi_2(s)$ for all $s ∈ S$. Prove: $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$.
2. For every $s ∈ S$, let $w_s ∈ W$. Prove that there is a unique $K$-linear map $\varphi : V → W$ such that $\varphi(s) = w_s$.

**My Thinking:**

1. Suppose $\varphi_1(s) = x$, then $\varphi_2(s) =x \:$ for all $s \in S$. Then we have $\varphi_1^{-1}(x) =s\:$ and $\:\varphi_2^{-1}(x)=s \:$ for all $x\in W $. So $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2.$
2. By 1) we have that $\varphi$ is unique.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning for 1 seems a little bit off. For the fact that the maps need not be invertible so your preimage could contain multiple elements, furthermore you then prove something odd, you say that the preimage of every element in $W$ is equal to s, which clearly does not always have to hold(take for example $V=W$ and the identity map on $V$). You have to show that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ map every element of $V$ to the same element in $W$, i.e. $$\forall v\in V: \phi_1(v)=\phi_2(v)$$I will try to help you understand my proof if you have any questions, so here we go:

1. Assume that for all $s\in S$ we know $\phi_1(s)=\phi_2(s)$, then take any $v\in V$. As $S$ is a basis we know there exist $\alpha_s\in K$ such that $v=\sum_{s\in S}\alpha_s s$. Now as the $\phi$'s are linear we can use the linearity together with the base representation to deduce the following $$\phi_1(v)\overset{\textrm{base representation}}{=}\phi_1(\sum_{s\in S}\alpha_s s)\overset{\textrm{linearity}}{=}\sum_{s\in S}\alpha_s \phi_1(s)\overset{\textrm{assumption}}{=}\sum_{s\in S}\alpha_s \phi_2(s)\overset{\textrm{linearity}}{=}\phi_2(\sum_{s\in S}\alpha_s s)\overset{\textrm{base representation}}{=}\phi_2(v)$$
   Now as $v\in V$ was arbitrary we know that $\phi_1=\phi_2$.
2. As you already noted correctly the uniqueness of such a map follows from 1) but we still have to show the existence! Showing that there exists something unique always is a two part exercise. As the first part is already done in 1) we can concentrate on the second one. As we know that $S$ is a basis of $V$ the idea how to construct such a map is somewhat natural. If $v=\sum_{s\in S}\alpha_s s$ is a base representation of $v\in V$ then we just define $$\phi(v)=\sum_{s\in S}\alpha_s w_s$$ So we just define $\phi$ on the basis of $V$. Now we still need to prove that this map is linear as we want to construct a linear map, which i am sure you can do on your own so i will leave this as an exercise to you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help! Can i say by 1) that this map is linear?

Comment: You mean the map constructed in 2? No you cannot, because in 1) you assume the existence of the linear map, whereas in 2) you need to show that there actually exists such a linear map.

Comment: So i do $\phi(av+bu)$ = ... = $a\phi(v) + b\phi(u)$?

Comment: Exactly, just insert into the definition of $\phi$ :)

Comment: Alright thank you!